# Does WIndows 8 include a FTP client?

Tags: windows-8, ftp

I'm very new to Windows 8 but would like to know if there are any good features or client tools available for FTP (like filezilla)?

Comment: May I know the reason of downvote?

Comment: Dewsworld, you have been downvoted because your question doesn't show any research effort. A simple Google search or a search in the Windows Store would have been enough. Filezilla will work on Windows 8 and maybe there are FTP clients in the store. Your question is more something for a forum. Superuser (and all StackExchange sites) are Q&A sites. Pose clear questions and say what steps you have undertaken, and you will get decent answers.

Comment: I'm used to filezilla, so I thought maybe something's better here on Windows 8, something with the release.

Comment: You might want to check the faq (http://superuser.com/faq). Superuser isn't really meant for asking a list of links/apps/resources/...

Comment: question is closed by mistake. windows7 has ftp.exe and ftp as folder support. It is possible to answer the same to windows8.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer can navigate FTP servers, and has supported that for a very long time (probably since it first was released).

I think you can map a FTP server to a drive letter using the regular "map network drive" functionality, which should allow you to upload as well as download if you have the proper privileges on the FTP server.